# Python + OpenWeatherMap + Flet: ошибка 'daily'

Tags: python, requests, datetime, openweathermap, flet

OpenWeatherMap не хочет давать мне название дней.

Сам урок: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OEyYTdEah4&t=2921s (таймкод 56:35)

Ошибка, которую я получаю:

```
  File "C:\Users\bande\Documents\PycharmProjects\weather_app\main.py", line 290, in _bot_data
    response['daily'][index]['dt']
    ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'daily'
```

Вот куски моего кода:

Основной

```
def _bot_data():
    _bot_data = []
    #range is a number of days for forecast => limited by the API key
    for index in range(1, 8):
        _bot_data.append(
            Row(
                spacing=5,
                alignment="spaceBetween",
                controls=[
                    Row(
                        expand=1,
                        alignment="start",
                        controls=[
                            Container(
                                alignment=alignment.center,
                                content=Text(
                                    #week day display
                                    datetime.datetime.weekday(
                                        datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                                            response['daily'][index]['dt']
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            )
        )
    return _bot_data
 
 
def _bottom():
    _bot_column = Column(
        alignment="center",
        horizontal_alignment="center",
        spacing=25,
    )
 
    for data in _bot_data():
        _bot_column.controls.append(data)
 
 
    bottom = Container(
        padding=padding.only(top=280, left=20, right=20, bottom=20),
        content=_bot_column
    )
    return bottom
```

Кусок запросов

```
API_KEY = "мой API ключ"
BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
CITY = "Minsk"
COUNTRY = "BY"
days_en = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
days = days_en
 
url = BASE_URL + "appid=" + API_KEY + "&q=" + CITY
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

Используемые библиотеки

```
import datetime
import flet as ft
from flet import *
import requests
import datetime as dt
import math
```

Когда я пытался изменить запрос на responce['dt'], я получил дни, которые я так хотел, но каждый день из списка повторялся огромное кол-во раз (по типу: 20 понедельников, 20 вторников и т.д.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец-то я нашел решение проблемы. OpenWeatnerMap имеет несколько форм вызова API. Я запрашивал по названию города, но чтобы получить прогноз на несколько дней нужно запрашивать по широте и долготе (еще одна форма вызова API).

Решение должно выглядеть так: Запросить широту и долготу через название города, а затем записать эти данные в переменные и вставить в другую форму запроса API. Вуаля.

Пример вызова API:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=33.44&lon=-94.04&exclude=hourly,daily&appid={ключ API}
```

Источник:
https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api.